# I want that if a user click on the marked image than reels start playing on other page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I want that if a user click on the marked image than reels start playing on other page for eg YouTube shorts so i first added a on click on the image and imported app.js file from the reels folder but it is not working so is their any way to do that pls if you are not sure about how to do that at least try if you didn't work no problem we will get a way that didn't work. just try!
i am not a very good programmer
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVlkw.png)

```
import { Header } from "../../features/theme/Header";
import styles from "./Home.module.css";
import { useAppSelector } from "../../app/hooks";
import { Feed } from "../../features";


export function Home(): JSX.Element {
  const { currentUserImage } = useAppSelector((state) => state.currentUser);

  return (
    <div className={styles.home}>
      <Header page="Home" />
      <div className={styles.tweetField}>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>Mowe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
          <h1>Haewae</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" onClick={reels}/>
          <h1>‎ ‎ ‎  Lveewe</h1>
        </div>
        <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
          <img src={currentUserImage} alt=""/>
          <h1>gy</h1>
        </div>
        <div>

          <div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Feed />
    </div>
  );

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you already have. That way people will know what they're working with.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn done pls see now

Comment: So am I getting this correctly? You're trying to navigate to a link on an external website when you're clicking on the image? If so, just wrap your image in an <a>-Tag and add the link to the href-attribute.

Comment: that i have added after see a post ignore that import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by that. So did it work?

Comment: @GabeRAMturn forget it can see my new edited code again

Comment: I don't see any changes...

Comment: ignore import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

Comment: I'm really confused... I don't see any import for { useNavigate } and that's also not what I was talking about. Did you try wraping the <img> with a <a>-Tag?

Comment: @GabeRAMturn sorry i was also confused i dont try

Comment: Give it a try and tell me if it worked and if it did what you wanted.

Comment: @GabeRAMturn can i get your social media so that we can chat

Comment: @GabeRAMturn i dont understand that can you give a example?

Comment: @ its a other project that I want to redirect to

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="YOUTUBE-SHORTS-LINK" className={styles.userAvatar}>
 <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
 <h1>‎ ‎ ‎  Lveewe</h1>
</a>
```

or

```
<a href="YOUTUBE-SHORTS-LINK">
    <div className={styles.userAvatar}>
      <img src={currentUserImage} alt="" />
      <h1>‎ ‎ ‎  Lveewe</h1>
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: its a other project that I want to add to the project Is their in my project folder